# clean morphological operation

Tags: matlab, morphological-analysis

In MATLAB documentation I can the see the clean morphological operation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html). The issue is that I'm not able to use it. I know how to use the structured element, but if I for instance type `imclean(img,SE)` or `clean(img,SE)`, I get an error as an undefined function. How should the function be used?

Comment: Please `stop` using `code formatting` for `things` that you `think` are `important`.  It makes it `very` hard to `read` your question.  Code formatting is for code, not for emphasis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no functions called `clean` or `imclean` in Matlab.

Matlab has a general morphology function for binary images (`bwmorph`) that takes strings as input for what operation to perform. So what you want to do is

```
bwmorph(img,'clean')
```

(This is based on R2013b - but this holds for other recent versions too AFAIK)